# Comparing list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I started to learn Haskell 2 weeks ago, so this question might be easy solved - It would be great if someone could explain me even simple steps.

I need tuples to be compared for their second component:

```
[(String, Double)] -> [(String, Double)]
```

So I want to get a list with highest Double value:

```
[("Example1", 10.0), ("Example2", 20.0), ("Example3", 30.0), ("Example4", 15.0), ("Example5", 30.0")]
```

As the snd of Example3 and Example 5 have the highest component (measured at Double component) I get this solution:

```
[("Example3", 30.0), "Example5, 30.0)]
```

Thanks, Wornz

Comment: Don't worry about doing anything fancy at first; try implementing the naive solution first: write one function to find the largest `Double` value among all the tuples, then write another function that collects all the tuples containing that value. Once you've done that, you may find it easier to write a function that can collect the necessary list of tuples in one pass.

Answer (score 1):

You must first sort the list by the value for each tuple. This value can be accessed using the `snd` function

Use the sortBy function which can be imported from `Data.List` and the comparing function which can be imported from `Data.Ord` to sort the list by the value for each tuple.

The following code will work.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

findMax :: Eq a1 => Ord a1 => [(a0, a1)]  -> [(a0, a1)] 
findMax list = [x | x <- sorted, (snd x) == (snd (head sorted))]
    where sorted = reverse $ sortBy (comparing snd) list
```

Running this code in GHCI we get the desired result.

```
*Main> let test = [("Example1", 10.0), ("Example2", 20.0), ("Example3", 30.0), ("Example4", 15.0), ("Example5", 30.0)]
*Main> findMax test
[("Example5",30.0),("Example3",30.0)]
```